# Using the same factor mapping for multiple columns in R

Tags: r, dplyr, categorical-data

I'm trying to figure out how to use the same factor "mapping" for more than one column.

For example, here's a data set of imaginary tennis matches, in which one player was the favorite and the other player was the underdog:

```
df <- tribble(
  ~game, ~favorite, ~underdog,
  #-----|----------|----------
  1,     "Mary",     "Susan",
  2,     "Susan",    "John",
  3,     "Mary",     "Joe",
  4,     "Joe",      "Dave",
  5,     "Susan",    "Dave"
)
```

Note that there are favorites who are never underdogs (Mary) and underdogs who are never favorites (John, Dave).

I'd like to create a factor that works for both the favorite and underdog columns. For instance, if I now enter

```
df %<>% mutate(favorite=factor(favorite))
```

then Joe is 1, Mary is 2, and Susan is 3, since the default is alphabetical order.

How can I now change the underdog column to a factor so that every time Joe shows up there he is assigned 1, Mary gets 2, and so on?

My requirements/hopes/desires:

1. In practice there will be a lot of rows and different entries, so hand coding is not an option;
2. I'd like to be able to do this in the middle of a chain, with pipes;
3. At the end, I'd like to be able to run code like `filter(favorite=="Susan" | underdog=="Susan")`.

I looked but couldn't find where this has been done before. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the `unique` players and then use it as `factor` levels for both the columns.

```
unique_players <- unique(unlist(df[-1]))
df[-1] <- lapply(df[-1], factor, levels = unique_players)
df[-1]
# A tibble: 5 x 2
#  favorite underdog
#  <fct>    <fct>   
#1 Mary     Susan   
#2 Susan    John    
#3 Mary     Joe     
#4 Joe      Dave    
#5 Susan    Dave
```

With pipes it would be

```
library(dplyr)    
df <- df %>% mutate_at(-1, factor, levels = unique_players)
```

So if you convert it to numeric you'll have the same number for similar names.

```
sapply(df[-1], as.numeric)   

#     favorite underdog
#[1,]        1        2
#[2,]        2        4
#[3,]        1        3
#[4,]        3        5
#[5,]        2        5
```

Comment: I was thinking of using sets, but this solution does the same thing without all that overhead. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

We can specify the `levels`

```
library(dplyr)
df%>%
   mutate(favorite = factor(favorite, levels = unique(underdog)))
```

---

If we need both columns to be `factor`, use `mutate_at`

```
df %>%
   mutate_at(vars(favorite, underdog), ~ factor(., levels = unique(underdog)))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply; this is a clever idea and gets us most of the way there. But it leaves the favorites who are not in the underdog columns (Mary) as NA's.